# Save String from EditText to SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

Good evening!

I would like to know if its possible to save in my Android project the String that the user is typing in a EditText field after pressing the button "save"  with SQLite.

I will really appreciate if someone can send me also a link of an already existing example.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES ,YOU CAN**

[here some from medium](https://ssaurel.medium.com/learn-to-save-data-with-sqlite-on-android-b11a8f7718d3)

[here some from tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

here some information that you need to know :
if you use sqlite you need alot of hard work, like create table ,query , some map data t POJO (your model object)(easier with [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)), need databasehelper class.....
but for room database it much easier for sure with that dao inferace for query data(it still sqlite but with a better version) with room it help you create table without your query , all you need just update the version once you do something new [room database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).